# Builder C++ (XE7) compiler Error 2315 when accessing an auto created DataModule in Project cpp file

Tags: c++builder

I am converting an old project written in Delphi 7 to C++Builder (XE7).

In a Delphi 7 project file, I can easily access auto-created Forms and DataModules by using their references. but in C++Builder, when I do the same thing, I get this error :

> E2315 'con1' is not a member of 'TDM1', because the type is not yet defined.

Here's a part of c++ project file:

```
Application->Initialize();
Application->MainFormOnTaskBar = true;
Application->CreateForm(__classid(TfrmMain), &frmMain);
Application->CreateForm(__classid(TDM1), &DM1);
DM1->con1->Open();//ERROR 2315
Application->Run();
```

What's the workaround to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you are attempting, you need to add an `#include` statement for `TDM1`'s header file in your main project file.  In C++Builder, an auto-created Form/DataModule is merely forward-declared in the main project file by default, just to satisfy the reference for `CreateForm()`.  But, in order to access any members, you need access to the full class declaration.

That being said, given the code you have shown, the call to `con1->Open()` should be moved to `TDM1`'s constructor instead, so it is called automatically when `CreateForm(&DM1)` is called.  Then you don't need to know the full type of `TDM1` in the main project file.

Comment: Thank you @Remy ,